# IntelliJ IDEA 12 AJC compiler

Tags: intellij-idea, aspectj

I'm trying to set my Java compiler to AJC in IntelliJ IDEA 12.02 Community Edition, and have been following the instructions [provided here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-the-aspectj-compiler-ajc.html).

But I cannot find the plugin Spring-AOP and the plugin AspectJSupport downloaded from [here](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin?pr=idea&pluginId=4679). It is not supported in IDEA 12.02 when I try to add it to my plugins.

I've created a library for AspectJrt and restarted IntelliJ, but no option appears to change my Java compiler to AJC

Any help getting the AJC compiler for IDEA 12.02?

Comment: According to http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html AspectJ is not supported in the Community Edition.

Comment: That would explain it then, thanks @CrazyCoder